# Issue using Oracle ODBC driver in Script Task in SSIS 2008

Tags: c#, oracle, ssis, odbc

The issue I'm having may not have anything to do with SSIS but I wanted to be thorough.  I am attempting to have essentially the same code (using ODBC) accessing SQL Server, Sybase, and Oracle.  Everything except Oracle is working (not surprising) but I'm at a loss as to how to resolve this issue.

The Oracle driver is the 11.01.00.06 version. I am able to connect successfully to the instance but the call (to the function) fails.  I'm guessing the error has to do with the fact that the cursor is a parameter in this case (not true for SQL Server and Sybase) and I am not accounting for it.  There is no OdbcType for cursor though.

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

The error I am getting is - ERROR [07001] [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01008: not all variables bound

Calling code (C#)

```
    NetworkProviderCon = new OdbcConnection(strCon);
    NetworkProviderCon.Open();
    NetworkProviderCmd.Connection = NetworkProviderCon;

    NetworkProviderCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    NetworkProviderCmd.CommandText = "{CALL SP_NETWORK_IDL(?,?)}";

    NetworkProviderCmd.CommandTimeout = this.Variables.CADATABASECORETIMEOUT;

    //parameters to call SP   
    NetworkProviderParam1 = NetworkProviderCmd.Parameters.Add("@pdtStartTime", OdbcType.DateTime);
    NetworkProviderParam1.Value = strStartDate;
    NetworkProviderParam2 = NetworkProviderCmd.Parameters.Add("@pdtEndTime", OdbcType.DateTime);
    NetworkProviderParam2.Value = strEndDate;
    sqlDr = NetworkProviderCmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Procedure Parameters

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function XXXX.SP_NETWORK_IDL
(
/*************************************************
** Declare Parameters                           **
*************************************************/

   pRESULT_CURSOR IN OUT CURSOR_PACKAGE.RESULT_CURSOR               ,
   pdtStartTime   IN     CMC_NWPR_RELATION.NWPR_TERM_DT%TYPE := NULL,
   pdtEndTime     IN     CMC_NWPR_RELATION.NWPR_EFF_DT%TYPE  := NULL
)
return number
```

Comment: Do you have to have pRESULT_CURSOR as a parameter?

Comment: I have added pRESULT_CURSOR and have been able to make some progress but I am now stuck on how to define the Parameter for the RETURN number on the function.

Answer (score 0):

Your function requests 3 parameters, but you are passing only 2.

```
NetworkProviderCmd.Parameters.Add
  ("@pRESULT_CURSOR", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
//NetworkProviderCmd.Parameters["pRESULT_CURSOR"].Value will store your output
```

**UPD**:

[MSDN: Using Parameters with an OleDbCommand or OdbcCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx)

```
NetworkProviderParam0 = NetworkProviderCmd.Parameters.Add("@pRESULT_CURSOR", OracleType.Cursor);
NetworkProviderParam0.Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;
```

P.S.: I can not find OdbcType for cursor

**UPD2**:

```
NetworkProviderCon = new OdbcConnection(strCon);
NetworkProviderCon.Open();

OdbcCommand NetworkProviderCmd = new OdbcCommand();
NetworkProviderCmd.CommandText = "{? = SP_NETWORK_IDL(?,?,?)}";
NetworkProviderCmd.Connection = NetworkProviderCon;
NetworkProviderCmd.CommandTimeout = this.Variables.CADATABASECORETIMEOUT;
NetworkProviderCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

//parameters to call SP 
NetworkProviderCmd.Parameters.Add("pRESULT_CURSOR", OracleType.Cursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput; //NetworkProviderParam1
NetworkProviderCmd.Parameters.Add("pdtStartTime", OdbcType.DateTime).Value = strStartDate; //NetworkProviderParam2
NetworkProviderCmd.Parameters.Add("pdtEndTime", OdbcType.DateTime).Value = strEndDate; //NetworkProviderParam3
NetworkProviderCmd.Parameters.Add("RETURN_VALUE", OdbcType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue; //NetworkProviderParam4
```

Comment: I have made progress on this front but the issue I am stuck on now is that I cannot determine how to properly represent the RETURN value from the function.  When I wrapped the function in a procedure I am able to successfully execute the code (this is not a long term solution) but when I go back to calling the function I am getting the original error. Does anyone know how to wrap the return as an ODBCParm?  I tried . . .             Param3 = NetworkProviderCmd.Parameters.Add(new OdbcParameter("@RETURN_VALUE", OdbcType.Int));
            Param3.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;